# Why tomcat throw NullPointException when I use pointcut for args()?

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspect

I try to use AspectJ pointcut for args(), but run in springboot with tomcat it threws NullPointException.

Since it reported a null pointer exception, and I debugged it when the variable logger of the GenericFilterBean variable is null, I don't know if I need to add extra configuration or what?

I would be grateful if anyone knows how to solve this problem.

error log :

```
2018-11-26 11:07:22.952 ERROR 12620 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [requestContextFilter]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:240) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4491) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:370) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9c83fa9f.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ccaf20b3.getWebServer(<generated>) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at cn.piumnl.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

2018-11-26 11:07:22.953 ERROR 12620 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [hiddenHttpMethodFilter]

// Omitting part of the error message, it like above log

2018-11-26 11:07:22.954 ERROR 12620 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [characterEncodingFilter]

// Omitting part of the error message, it like above log

2018-11-26 11:07:22.954 ERROR 12620 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [formContentFilter]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:240) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4491) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:370) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9c83fa9f.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ccaf20b3.getWebServer(<generated>) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at cn.piumnl.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

2018-11-26 11:07:22.955 ERROR 12620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2018-11-26 11:07:22.955 ERROR 12620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2018-11-26 11:07:23.056  INFO 12620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-11-26 11:07:23.060  WARN 12620 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-11-26 11:07:23.071  INFO 12620 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-26 11:07:23.078 ERROR 12620 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at cn.piumnl.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9c83fa9f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ccaf20b3.getWebServer(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

the code:

ArgsAop.java

```java
package cn.piumnl.demo;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ArgsAop {

    @Pointcut("args(entity)")
    public void pointcut(ArgsEntity entity) {
    }

    @After(value = "pointcut(entity)", argNames = "entity")
    public void test(ArgsEntity entity) {
        System.out.println("args(entity)");
    }
}
```

ArgsEntity.java

```java
package cn.piumnl.demo;

public class ArgsEntity {}
```

DemoApplication.java

```java
package cn.piumnl.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cn.piumnl</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointcut potentially targets the whole world, even Spring framework components. The error message will go away if you limit its scope to what you actually want to intercept, e.g.

```java
@Pointcut("within(cn.piumnl.demo..*) && args(entity)")
```

The alternative would be to explicitly exclude the packages leading to problems with your pointcut, but I still prefer the white-listing option to this one:

```java
@Pointcut("!within(org.springframework..*) && !within(com.sun..*) && args(entity)")
```